# Mobu: Motion Files Naming Scheme for Unity

Tags: unity, python

When exporting takes as several fbx files in Motionbuilder 2014 with **File > Motion File Export...**, the files are named like so:

> file_Take1.fbx
>
> file_Take2.fbx
>
> file_Take3.fbx

In order for the motion files to be loaded into Unity correctly, I have to rename them to:

> file@Take1.fbx
>
> file@Take2.fbx
>
> file@Take3.fbx

Having to replace underscores with '@' is fine for small projects but can become time consuming when working with many takes in large projects.

Is there a way to change the default naming scheme in Motionbuilder, through preferences or python scripting, so that the default underscore is replaced with an '@'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to write a solution after some python experimentation. To get this to work, save the code into a python file (.py), drop the file into Motionbuilder, and click execute.

Here's the code if you're interested:

```
from pyfbsdk import *
import os

#save default name here for quick execution
dName = "Untitled.fbx"

lSystem = FBSystem()
lApplication = FBApplication()

lFileName = lApplication.FBXFileName

FileDlg = FBFilePopup()
FileDlg.Style = FBFilePopupStyle.kFBFilePopupSave
FileDlg.Caption = "Saving Motion Files"
FileDlg.FileName = dName
FileDlg.Filter = "*.fbx"

if FileDlg.Execute():
    mSuccess = True
    lOptions = FBFbxOptions(False) 
    lOriginalTake = lSystem.CurrentTake

    lFileNameText = os.path.splitext(FileDlg.FileName)[0];
    lFileNameExt = os.path.splitext(FileDlg.FileName)[1]

    for lTake in lSystem.Scene.Takes:
        lSystem.CurrentTake = lTake
        lFullFileName = FileDlg.Path + '\\' +  lFileNameText + '@' + lTake.Name + lFileNameExt;

        if lApplication.FileExport(lFullFileName) == False:
            mSuccess = False
            print lFullFileName + " Failed...";
        else:
            print lFullFileName + " OK!";



    lSystem.CurrentTake = lOriginalTake

    if mSuccess:
        print "Export successful!"
    else:
        print "Export failed."
else:
    print "Export canceled."
```